# App that Opens Adobe-DPS App

Tags: adobe-dps

I need to create a link that tells the device to open my App. 
Is this somehow possible ?
I found this [old tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/indesigndocs/2012/06/link-to-dps-app-test.html) but the 'DPS Viewer Builder' Apparently doesn't exist anymore in the 2015 edition.

Answer (score -1):

The DPS 2015, now name Adobe Experence Manager Mobile (AEM Mobile) still allow you to link to an app, using the publication-ID.
Check the [Create deep links from outside the app](https://helpx.adobe.com/digital-publishing-solution/help/hyperlinks.html#external-deep-links) to set that.